# spark cluster using yarn and fair scheduler hits maximum cores per user

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, scheduler

I am making multiple yarn job submissions into a cluster using the fair scheduler and dynamic allocation. I can load up many jobs in the queue. What I see is that the jobs will run up to 18 worker cores, then it will hold off the jobs downstream, until one of the active cores is finished. Where would this constraint be from? is it a yarn setting, or a fair scheduler setting?

Comment: Look at your `maxAMShare` setting in the fair-scheduler.